# Как запаролить админ часть сайта на Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, безопасность

Есть сайт, разрабатываемый на Ruby on Rails, и несколько таблиц, хранящихся в базе postgresql, необходимых для работы сайта. Есть админ страница со списком этих таблиц.

**Задача:** Поставить пароль на админ страницу.

Думал сам, гуглил. Примеры только на javascript или php. *Одно из неправильных решений:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WhitePark</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
<body>
<form action=index.php method=POST>
<input type=text name=pas>
<input type=submit>
</form>

<?PHP 
if (isset($_POST['pas']))
{
 if ($_POST['pas'] == 'lol')
 <!-- lol=password -->
   {
     echo "Доступ открыт";
     <!-- databases -->
     <div> <h1>Это список баз данных, используемый приложением</h1> </div>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/opinions"> мнения</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/events"> события</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/type_events"> типы событий</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/photo_in_events"> фото событий </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/slayders"> слайдера</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/photo_in_slayder_ts"> фото в слайдерах</a></li>
     </ul>
   }
   else
   {
     echo "access denied";
   } 
}
?></body>
</html>
```

Не работает, так как Ruby не php.

Как защитить эту страницу, используя Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться **Basic HTTP Authentication**. В контроллере вашей страницы (или в общем контроллере для всей админки), пропишите:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: 'user', password: ENV['HTTP_ADMIN_PASS']
end
```

И при попытке зайти на страницу этого контроллера, браузер спросит у вас имя и пароль. В данном примере именем будет `user`, а пароль - хранится в переменной окружения `HTTP_ADMIN_PASS`.

> Вы можете вместо `ENV['HTTP_ADMIN_PASS']` прописать и пароль напрямую (например `'123'`). Но хранить пароли и другие чувствительные данные в переменных окружения, а не в исходном коде - считается хорошей практикой. В рельсах легко управлять переменными окружения можно с помощью гема [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro).